# Accessing php files out of root folder(Laravel)

Tags: magento, laravel

Inside my Magento Project folder I want to install laravel so that I can access `Mage` from laravel. Directory structure is following

```
Magento(root)
  --laravel
  --app
  ...
  ...
```

How can I achieve That? Or suggest any other way so that I can access magento from laravel like following.

```
require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**UPDATE**

Controller Location relative to magento

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\custom\app\controllers\ProductsController.php
```

Comment: Did you try this code? Are you facing any issue?

Comment: yes I tried this code. It did not work. showed error

Failed opening required '../app/Mage.php'

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `dirname()` function to solve this problem.

```
require_once (dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))))).'/app/Mage.php');
```

I don't think this the nice or smart way, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: dirname() provides the parent folder , so if it's working it's totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the path is correct, it should work.

Use this one

```
require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/Mage.php'));
```

Comment: Provide the path to the Laravel controller file (relative to magento installation). Btw, what's the error?

Comment: Controller Location:
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\custom\app\controllers\ProductsController.php

Error:
Failed opening required '../app/Mage.php'

Comment: require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../app/Mage.php'));

Answer (score 1):

Your path ( `require_once ('../app/Mage.php');` ) is not correct that's why you are facing this issue.Except this logic wise your code is correct.

If you are running your code from somefile.php in laravel then it should work.

```
Magento(root)
  --laravel
      |__somefile.php  
  --app
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: I dont understand your process clearly. I am calling from some php file in laravel, which is controller. But doesn't work.

Comment: @Alvi_1987 If you can update question with proper location of your controller relative to Mageno, I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone useful:

```
require_once (dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))))).'/../app/Mage.php');

\Mage::app();
$blocks = \Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();


foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    echo $block->getTitle()."<br>";
}
```